# OleDbException (x80040E14): Syntax error in Insert into statement

Tags: c#, ms-access, oledb, sql-insert

Can anyone help with this issue please? I've tried so many different things and I'm still getting this error. The error points to the line cmd.ExecuteNonQuery(). I've checked the Insert string a million times now and I don't see what's wrong with. Thanks!

```
OleDbConnection myConnection = new OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + targetPath);                        
try
{
    for (int i = 0; i < listOfDBTables.Count; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 1; j < listOfDBTables[i].Rows.Count; j++)
        //Don't include the header
        {
            OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("INSERT INTO POP(Global Customer, Sold To #, Material #, Material Description, Customer ID, Customer Name, City, State, Country, Market Code, Unit Cost, Invoice Date, [Month], Quantity, UoM, KG, [Year]) Values (@globCust,@soldToNum,@matNum,@matDesc,@custID,@custName,@city,@state,@country,@mktCode,@cost,@invDate,@month,@quantity,@uom,@kg,@year)", myConnection);

            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@globCust", listOfDBTables[i].Rows[j][0].ToString());
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@soldToNum", listOfDBTables[i].Rows[j][1].ToString());
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@matNum", listOfDBTables[i].Rows[j][2].ToString());
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@matDesc", listOfDBTables[i].Rows[j][3].ToString());
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@custID", listOfDBTables[i].Rows[j][4].ToString());
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@custName", listOfDBTables[i].Rows[j][5].ToString());
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@city", listOfDBTables[i].Rows[j][6].ToString());
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@state", listOfDBTables[i].Rows[j][7].ToString());
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@country", listOfDBTables[i].Rows[j][8].ToString());
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@mktCode", listOfDBTables[i].Rows[j][9].ToString());
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@cost", listOfDBTables[i].Rows[j][10].ToString());
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@invDate", listOfDBTables[i].Rows[j][11].ToString());
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@month", listOfDBTables[i].Rows[j][12].ToString());
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@quantity", listOfDBTables[i].Rows[j][13].ToString());
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@uom", listOfDBTables[i].Rows[j][14].ToString());
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@kg", listOfDBTables[i].Rows[j][15].ToString());
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@year", listOfDBTables[i].Rows[j][16].ToString());

            myConnection.Open();
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
    }
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
}
finally
{
    myConnection.Close();
}
```

Comment: Wrap your column names in [..]. ex: [Global Customer]

Comment: Your provider may only handle unnamed parameters (using `?`)

Comment: I'm still getting some errors, but I seem to be making progress. Wrapping all of the column names in brackets may have done the trick. I will post again if I solve this. Thanks @MarcusH

Comment: Solved. I had to wrap each column name in brackets as well as the table name. Thanks guys!

Answer (score 0):

you should put your columns in [], e.g make it [Sold To #] instead of Sold To #